# Android glowing seekbar

Tags: android, android-xml, seekbar, glow

I want to make a seekbar that has a glowing effect like that. I tried a lot of tricks. I could make it to be glow but not the left side. I tried to cut the left side and put it next to the seekbar but the resolution did not mach and it is an ugly solution anyway.

Can somebody give me some tips if it is possible to create on android

Check the image here:

[image: seekbar with glow effect]

Comment: it's cool...I asked similar question but still not get answer..check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463841/how-to-make-seekbar-like-this

Comment: I hope some UI fan + expert can solve our problem..:)